# How to "normalize" an html file?

Tags: html

Given an HTML file, the content of which was generated from various websites, it could have potential security problems, like:

```
<script>alert("XSS alert!")</script>
```

**Q:** What can we do to "clear" this HTML file? Run a:

```
sed '/<script/d'
```

several times? (the "`<script`" could be hidden in HTML, like: "`&lt;script`")

Comment: you may find this useful. http://security.stackexchange.com/q/32616/21234

Comment: Are there any potentially "good" scripts that need to run on the page? Also, it's not always in a script tag (think onload, onmouseover, etc)

Comment: I highly recommend looking into [Content Security Policy](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38001/xss-prevention-through-content-security-policy) as a defense in depth approach to solving XSS issues.

Comment: there are no "good" scripts that need to be run on the page!

Answer (score 3):

Since the HTML was assembled from heterogeneous sources, chances are that you're not interested in any scripts it may contain. So your approach looks viable to me.

I believe that the most practical and maintainable approach would be to make a list of **allowed** HTML tags and attributes (you are likely to not want, more than simply not *need*, CSS code; so `id`, `style` and `class` attributes may be discarded altogether). Tags like `IFRAME` and attributes such as `onfocus` would very likely not be included in the list at all.

Once you have this, you can run your HTML through a parser that will drop any unknown tags and attributes. You may want to do this in two stages, a "tagsoup" cleaner (HTML Tidy or TagSoup or HTMLClean or BeautifulSoup - I'd try HTML Tidy first) and a full-fledged HTML parser.

This way you'd end up with a well-formed and defanged HTML code which can be then manipulated much better and in more safety.

I'd avoid regexp matching unless I really had no other alternative.

Comment: I agree with throwing a html parser at it. That way its output won't be really weird html that might be parsed incorrectly by some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the sed approach is this malicious input: `<scr<script>ipt>`. (Apply your sed to it and look at what comes out.) If you just try to sanitize the bad stuff, the bad guys will find a way through it. Instead, it's much safer that once you recognize the bad input, you refuse to accept any of it.

Even safer is a whitelist.